# How to set properties on matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, subplot

I'm adding a matplotlib figure to a canvas so that I may integrate it with pyqt in my application. I was looking around and using `plt.add_subplot(111)` seem to be the way to go(?) But I cannot add any properties to the subplot as I may with an "ordinary" plot.

figure setup

```py
figure1 = plt.figure()
canvas1 = FigureCanvas(figure1)
graphtoolbar1 = NavigationToolbar(canvas1, frameGraph1)

hboxlayout = qt.QVBoxLayout()
        
hboxlayout.addWidget(graphtoolbar1)
hboxlayout.addWidget(canvas1)
        
frameGraph1.setLayout(hboxlayout)
```

creating subplot and adding data

```py
df = quandl.getData(startDate, endDate, company)
          
ax = figure1.add_subplot(111)
ax.hold(False)
ax.plot(df['Close'], 'b-')
ax.legend(loc=0)
ax.grid(True)
```

I'd like to set x and y labels, but if I do `ax.xlabel("Test")`

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ylabel'
```

which is possible if I did it by not using subplot

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 4))
plt.plot(df['Close'], 'k-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Histogram')
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=25)
plt.show()
```

So I guess my question is, is it not possible to modify subplots further? Or is it possible for me to plot graphs in a pyqt canvas, without using subplots so that I may benefit from more properties for my plots?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`plt.subplot` returns a subplot object which is a type of axes object. It has two methods for adding axis labels: [`set_xlabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel) and [`set_ylabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel):

```
ax = plt.subplot('111')
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
```

You could also call `plt.xlabel` and `plt.ylabel` (like you did before) and specify the axes to which you want the label applied.

```
ax = plt.subplot('111')
plt.xlabel('X Axis', axes=ax)
plt.ylabel('Y Axis', axes=ax)
```

Since you only have one axes, you could also omit the `axes` kwarg since the label will automatically be applied to the current axes if one isn't specified.

```
ax = plt.subplot('111')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Is it possible to rotate the x labels ?

Comment: @vandelay Sure. You can use the `rotation` kwarg: `plt.xlabel('X Axis', rotation=30)`

Comment: I was more thinking with subplots :), as with ax. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @vandelay you want to rotate the plot itself? You can also just do `label = ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')` and then `label.set_rotation(30)`

Comment: I'd like to rotate the data on the x axis. I got dates on the x axis and they're all horizontal and cross into eachother

Comment: @vandelay Oh those are tick labels. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214290/rotated-axis-labels-are-placed-incorrectly-matplotlib)

Comment: That worked for me. Still, i find it very confusing to change the method's name when moving from plotting straight using pyplot (plt) to creating a figure and working with it.

Comment: Can you make set_size on subplots?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all matplotlib properties define a `set()` method. For example, Axes objects define a `set()` method that can be used to set axis labels, ticks, title etc. on subplots. Axis labels are Text objects (which can be accessed through `ax.yaxis.label` or `ax.xaxis.label`), which also define a `set()` method to change stuff.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white', figsize=(6,3))
ax.plot(range(5))
# set properties on this ax
ax.set(xlabel='X Axis', ylabel='Y Axis', title='Title', xticks=range(5))
ax.yaxis.label.set(rotation=0, ha='right')  # modify properties on ylabel
ax.title.set(fontsize=20);                  # change title properties
```

The very same job can also be done using `set_*` methods.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='white', figsize=(6,3))
ax.plot(range(5))
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')                          # set xlabel
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis', rotation=0, ha='right')  # set ylabel with properties
ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=20)               # set title
ax.set_xticks(range(5));                         # set xticks
```

[image: result]