# Having trouble to display the graph of a function

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a function f(x), how to ?

Generate the graph of the function and its derivative function on a figure with one bottom and top subplots that share the x-axis.
Both axes take their form with an input array with values from min to max
that are spaced by 0.5.
Each subplot must have a title
The top subplot must have the ylabel, whereas the bottom subplot must have both xlabel and ylabel
Each subplot shot have different styles of lines (colors, thickness, ...) and x ticks must also be in a different style(specifically the fontsize and rotation).

I did this :

```
#the function is f(x) while the derivative is df(x)

x = np.arange(min, max, 0.5) #scale

figure, (top, bottom) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize = [5.0, 7.0])
top.plot(x, f(x), 'b', linewidth = 5)
top.set_title(Function f(x))
top.ylabel('f(x)')
figure.set_xticks(colors = 'r', fontsize = 12, rotation = 30)

bottom.plot(x, df(x), 'g-', linewidth = 8) 
bottom.set_title('Derivative function of f(x)')
bottom.xlabel('x')
bottom.ylabel('df(x)')

plt.show(figure)
```

But it does not work. How could I fix everything ?

Edited for generalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) - x*np.cos(x) #The derivative is equal to x 

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.05)

figure, (top, bottom) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize = [5.0, 7.0])
top.plot(x, f(x), 'b', linewidth = 5)
top.set_title('Function f(x) = sin(x) - x*cos(x)')
top.set_ylabel('f(x)')
plt.tick_params(axis='x', colors = 'r', labelsize = 12, rotation = 30)

bottom.plot(x, x, 'g-', linewidth = 8) 
bottom.set_title('Derivative function of f(x)')
bottom.set_xlabel('x')
bottom.set_ylabel('df(x)')
bottom.tick_params(axis='x', colors = 'r')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

When something goes wrong, it really helps to read Python's error messages. If you don't understand the message, you can google it, which often leads to a useful StackOverflow answer.

For example, the message *"AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ylabel'"* leads to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662667/matplotlib-and-subplots-properties). In this case, the correct function name is `.set_ylabel()`. The difference between the ["Object Oriented Interface"](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) and the "old" "plt" interface, can be a bit confusing (it is due to historic reasons). It helps to give the "axes" returned by `plt.subplots()` a name such as `ax_top` to more easily figure out how example code maps to your situation.

To set the color, rotation etc. of the ticks, you can use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30, labelsize=12, labelcolor='red')`. This can be a bit tricky, the only way to "know" is to search for it on StackOverflow.

There are many [different line styles](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html). They can be set via the `linestyle=...` keyword. The most common ones also can be part of the code in the third parameter to `plot()`, e.g. `ax.plot(x, y, 'b--')` would use a blue dashed line style. (See also the [introductory tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html).)

Also note that `plt.show()` doesn't get the `figure` as parameter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x) - x * np.cos(x)  # The derivative is equal to x

x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.05)

figure, (ax_top, ax_bottom) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, figsize=[5.0, 7.0])
ax_top.plot(x, f(x), 'b', linewidth=1)
ax_top.set_title('Function f(x) = sin(x) - x*cos(x)')
ax_top.set_ylabel('f(x)')
ax_bottom.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30, labelsize=12, labelcolor='red')

ax_bottom.plot(x, x, 'g--', linewidth=2)
ax_bottom.set_title('Derivative function of f(x)')
ax_bottom.set_xlabel('x')
ax_bottom.set_ylabel('df(x)')

plt.tight_layout() # fits the axes and text nicely into the figure
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Are you sure the other answer is correct? It doesn't use linestyles (only thickness and color). It uses `plt.tick_params()` in a wrong way. With the latest matplotlib version (3.4.3) it throws an error for `plt.show(figure)`.