# Adding text into bar-chart graph in Matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need text at the x-axis in Matplotlib graph. I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
y=[5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]

plt.bar(x,y, color='g')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("Max Temperature for Months")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And my output is:

[image: My graph]

I don't know how to replace `x=[ ]` list with text (strings), it gives me error.

My desired graph is:

[image: My desied graph]

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it was helpful? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `plt.xticks()` function as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]

plt.bar(x,y, color='g')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Generate some labels to go on your graph. The list of strings must be the same length as your `x` and `y` lists:

```
LABELS = ["M","w","E","R","T"]
```

Plot them with the following:

```
plt.xticks(x, LABELS)

plt.title("Max Temperature for Months")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

See example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

Edit: For information on adjusting the location/orientation/position of your labels, see the matplotlib api documentation, and this question: [matplotlib ticks position relative to axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711338/matplotlib-ticks-position-relative-to-axis).

Edit: Added Image: 
[http://imgur.com/igjUGLb](https://imgur.com/igjUGLb)

Edit: To achieve the location and orientation that you need, you will find a great example in this question: [Matplotlib Python Barplot: Position of xtick labels have irregular spaces between eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477465/matplotlib-python-barplot-position-of-xtick-labels-have-irregular-spaces-betwee).

Implementing:

```
b = plt.bar(x,y, color='g')
xticks_pos = [0.5*patch.get_width() + patch.get_xy()[0] for patch in b]        
plt.xticks(xticks_pos, LABELS,rotation = 45)
```

gives: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arACh.jpg
Hope that helps.

Comment: Instead of `xticks_pos`, you could use `plt.bar(..., align='center')`.

Comment: To define `LABELS` you could use `import datetime`, `LABELS = [DT.datetime.strftime(DT.date(2001,xi,1), '%B') for xi in x]`.

Comment: @unutbu Great advice. Completely forgot about align. Much cleaner.